# Mandar File con Android a Mysql

Tags: android

Tengo una duda, es correcto guardar en la Base de Datos un File? y antes que nada se puede enviar un File a Mysql?.
Gracias espero sus respuestas

Comment: guardar en la Base de Datos un File? te refieres a guardarla como archivo en disco? si es eso la respuesta es "si".

Comment: Hola Elenasys gracias por tu respuesta, y es lo correcto guardar el File en Mysql?

Answer (score 1):

De seguro ya resolviste la duda pero para alguien mas que tenga esta pregunta.

Para guardar un archivo en la base de datos, puedes usar `longBlob` o un `BLOB`, esta es la documentación oficial para usar este tipo de dato [Blob](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

Este es un ejemplo de como utilizarlo, es una tabla para guardar **imagenes**

```
CREATE TABLE imagenes (
ID_IMAGEN INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
IMAGEN BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```